TypeScript type guards. How to get type narrowing AND suggestions?
I have assertIsDefined type guard with expected value.
I need to type narrowing to expected value with type suggestions.

For type narrowing i need to add  | unknown to generic type, and suggestions is not showing with it.
Without  | unknown in generic type, suggestions are showing, but type narrowing is not working.

What should I do with my type guard to make it work like a shine?
{
    const value_number1 = 123 as 3 | 123 | 777 | undefined;
    //     ^?
    //  INCURRECT BEHAVIOUR: remove '123' from ', 123' and 'Ctrl+Space' to no suggestions showed 
    assertIsDefined_withDetailedType(value_number1, 123);
    //  CURRECT BEHAVIOUR: calculated type of value_number1 is 123 
    console.log(value_number1);// value_number1: 123
    //           ^?
}
{
    const value_number2 = 123 as 3 | 123 | 777 | undefined;
    //     ^?
    //  CURRECT BEHAVIOUR: remove '123' from ', 123' and 'Ctrl+Space' to show SUGGESTIONS: should be [ 123, 3, 777 ] 
    assertIsDefined_withSuggestions(value_number2, 123);
    //  INCURRECT BEHAVIOUR: calculated type of value_number2 is 3 | 123 | 777 
    console.log(value_number2);// value_number2: 3 | 123 | 777
    //           ^?
}

function assertIsDefined_withDetailedType<T>(value: T | unknown | null | undefined, expected: T): asserts value is T {
    if (value == null || expected !== value) {
        throw new TypeError(`value should be defined and equal expected value`);
    }
}

function assertIsDefined_withSuggestions<T>(value: T | null | undefined, expected: T): asserts value is T {
    if (value == null || expected !== value) {
        throw new TypeError(`value should be defined and equal expected value`);
    }
}


typescriptlang.org/play v5.0.4 and upper
typescriptlang.org/play v4.9.5 and lower

I expect:
{
    const value_number2 = 123 as 3 | 123 | 777 | undefined;
    //     ^?
    //  CURRECT BEHAVIOUR: remove '123' from ', 123' and 'Ctrl+Space' to show SUGGESTIONS: should be [ 123, 3, 777 ] 
    assertIsDefined_withAllWeWant(value_number2, 123);
    //  CURRECT BEHAVIOUR: calculated type of value_number2 is 123 
    console.log(value_number2);// value_number2: 123
    //           ^?
}

// Some gorgeous type guard
function assertIsDefined_withAllWeWant(value: T/*code here?*/, expected: T): asserts value is T {
    if (value == null || expected !== value) {
        throw new TypeError(`value should be defined and equal expected value`);
    }
}



Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you very much. This is exactly what i am need.
The only note: this solution only works with TypeScript v5.4.5 and higher.

I’ll write an answer soon, but is there a dependency on an older version of TS that I should worry about?

@jcalz I am just worry about other people looking for answer. For my case i rewrite you answer for older TypeScript from v5.3.3 to v4.9.5 (for technical reason we are using TS v4.9.5).

I would write assertIsDefined() to be generic in both the type T of value and the type U of expected, where U is constrainted to both T (so it's a narrowing) and {} (so it's NonNullable; an intersection with the empty object type only prohibits null and undefined):
function assertIsDefined<T, U extends T & {}>(
    value: T, expected: U): asserts value is U {
    if (value == null || expected !== value) {
        throw new TypeError(`value should be defined and equal expected value`);
    }
}

Now you can only specify an expected as some non-nullish subtype of the type of value, and in TS5.4 and above you get nice autosuggestions as well:
const value = 123 as 3 | 123 | 777 | undefined;
//     ^? const value: 3 | 123 | 777 | undefined;

assertIsDefined(value, 123); // <-- autosuggest 3 | 123 | 777

console.log(value);
//           ^? const value: 123

Playground link to code
